# What does "to take someone oneself" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I will take you myself.

I don't quite understand these sentence. I've read it somewhere. But there was not a word about taking someone somewhere. And I couldn't find another meaning.

What does "to take someone oneself" mean?

Comment: Reflexive "myself" is just an "optional intensifier" here, so it's equivalent to *I (**not** someone else) will take you*. Only a full context (which you haven't provided) would tell us exactly what that means. The most likely *literal* meaning would be *I will escort / lead you somewhere*, but in certain contexts ***to take someone*** could mean ***to kill*** (or otherwise "defeat") someone.

Comment: Without context it's impossible to say. I would expect it to mean "I myself will take you [there]", but if you are convinced that that wasn't the meaning, that leaves us with 'take you as my wife/husband' (or in some other capacity).

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiomatic way of saying you will *personally* take someone somewhere, *instead of anybody else*.

For example, let's say you were trying to organise a lift/ride for somebody to get somewhere, and there was a choice of people who could be available to take that person where they wanted to go. Saying "I will take you there *myself*" is a way in which a native English speaker would show that they will be *personally* taking that person.